# How to embed an MDI Form in another application?

Tags: .net, winforms, mdi, mdiparent

we're trying to embed our application into another app which offers an interface via UserControl.

It's easy to create an user control that contains a normal Windows.Form. But how to do this if the form to be embedded has the property IsMdiContainer == true?

Thx

Comment: You don't, this isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will be possible [because](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.toplevel%28v=VS.90%29.aspx):

> A Multiple-document interface (MDI)
>   parent form must be a top-level
>   window.

If you try to set a parent to the MdiContainer, you will/should get an exception. The only way around this is to redesign the window you're trying to embed. Either do without the MDI concept or if you really need it, implement it as a custom control that behaves like an MDI but without the limitations. (This is a tall order most likely requiring a lot of custom drawing.)

There is actually a hack approach where you can re-parent windows at runtime from other processes via the [SetParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. So for example you can "steal" a calculator window app and host it inside another MDI but this tends to be highly unstable, especially for more complex apps. You would have to launch your MDI app as a separate process and then call SetParent from the hosted app. Might be worth a try if none of the above-mentioned options suit your needs but the most likely result will be a runtime exception.

Comment: There's no guarantee that `SetParent` will work properly for MDI *child* windows. You *might* be able to remove the `WS_EX_MDICHILD` style flag and re-parent it, but I've never tried it. In any case, it's not a good solution, as your answer explains.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach, it is no automatic but it will do the work.

1) Within your user control, declare your windows application, the one that is the MDI host.
2) Map the functionality of creating and handling new windows to a toolbar in your user control or you can map it to a custom control.
3) Every time you create a new windows set the MDI parent to the window you declare in step 1.

The main idea is in this post
[C# Panel As MDI Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941306/c-panel-as-mdi-container)

The approach has 1 problem. When you maximize your child window it maximize and cover all the user control area and you wont see its title bar. I believe that you can get rid of this error by setting the maximum size of the MDI child window a little less than the user control size